# How to close out of redis om connection?

Tags: redis

Recently I got an error saying I maxed out of connection. Magically the error disappeared, but I can't have this happening on a live website.

How/where to close out of the redis connection? I'm using redis om. Can't find any documentation on it.

```
 const client = new Client();

 async function connect() {
   if (!client.isOpen()) {
     await client.open(process.env.REDIS_URL);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `client.close()`. Documentation in is the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-om/v/0.3.6) near the top. Look for *Connect to Redis with a Client*.

Comment: Where do we add "await client.close()" in practice? Following Redis Stack Workshop, do we add it in the client.js? Or person.js (with the entity and schema)?

Comment: Ideally, you open it once and never close it. But if you set up these processes a lot, then you could always do it when the process shuts down.